# The argument type 'Userr' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User'

Tags: firebase, flutter, class, dart, google-cloud-firestore

class userResult accept the instance of Userr class but when i try to do it shows this error

```
> Userr user = Userr.fromDocument(doc);
            UserResult searchResult = UserResult(user);
            searchResults.add(searchResult);

class UserResult extends StatelessWidget {
  User user;

  UserResult(this.user);
```

Comment: Userr user instead of  User user in UserResult class

Comment: You seem to have two classes: 1) `User`, 2) `Userr` with double `rr`. The two are no the same, and you're trying to assign a double-r `Userr` to a single-r `User` in `UserResult`. That field inside `UserResult` should probably be declared as `Userr user;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `User` to `Userr` inside your `UserResult` class.

```
Userr user = Userr.fromDocument(doc);
            UserResult searchResult = UserResult(user);
            searchResults.add(searchResult);

class UserResult extends StatelessWidget {
  // Changed User to Userr
  Userr user;

  UserResult(this.user);
```